# System.Timers.Timer timer1_Elapsed not firing! Help!

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am creating another windows service and my timer is not ticking and I have no idea why! 
I am using system.timers.timer as I have in previous services and it doesn't work.
I have tried attaching to it but it doesn't seem to do anything.

My code:

```
    namespace ExpiryNotifier
{
    public partial class ExpiryNotifier : ServiceBase
    {
        public ExpiryNotifier()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("ExpiryNotifier"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("ExpiryNotifier", "ExpiryNotifier");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "ExpiryNotifier";
            eventLog1.Log = "ExpiryNotifier";
        }
        private Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Started");
            timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;
            timer1.Interval = 10000;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Stopped");
            timer1.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("timer tick");
            timer1.Stop();

            EmailerService.EmailerService service = new EmailerService.EmailerService();
            DataSet expiringQualifications = service.GetDetailsOfExpiringQualifications();

            if(expiringQualifications.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
            {
                foreach(DataRow rw in expiringQualifications.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["EmailAddress"].ToString()) )
                    {
                        if (rw["QualAwardDescription"] != null)
                        {
                            service.SendQualExpiryEmail(rw["EmailAddress"].ToString(), rw["firstName"].ToString(),
                                                        rw["QualAwardDescription"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Bex

Comment: Can you see the "Service Started" entry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

System.Timers.Timer is an ugly timer.  One nasty thing it does is swallow exceptions raised by the Elapsed event handler.  Which will kill your timer since you stop it when entering the method.  No notification whatsoever, it just stops working.

You have to at least add exception handling to this code so you can log the exception and stop the service.

Also beware the bug in your OnStart() method, you'll keep adding an event handler each time the service gets started.  The Elapsed event runs multiple times, in itself a good way to bomb something.

Consider System.Threading.Timer, it doesn't have any of these problems.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to the bug. I moved it to the initialize and now the service has actually started working. Will it be ok in the initialize?

Comment: If it works then it's ok.  Only change Enabled in OnStart/Stop.  And add the exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

System.Timers.Timer.Start() has a same function as System.Timers.Timer.Enabled=true;
System.Timers.Timer.Stop() has a same function as System.Timers.Timer.Enabled=false;

Those 2 methods internally sets Enabled property to true or false which starts or stops the timer.

Check if you have permission to write to eventlog. You can also check for errors in eventlog.

System.Timers.Timer is not thread safe. Make sure you use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think `timer1_Elapsed` needs to use the event delegate, so

```
timer1_Elapsed +=  new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Though I would recommend the System.Threading.Timer for inside a service, as it will correctly throw exceptions inside the elapsed event.  System.Timers.Timer just swallows them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it works but you probably a better way to debug it. Who knows maybe your `eventLog1` is null

Update your onstart to include this

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
     {
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            if (arg == "DEBUG_SERVICE")
                    DebugMode();

        }

     #if DEBUG
         DebugMode();
     #endif

     eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Started");
     timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;
     timer1.Interval = 10000;
     timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

private static void DebugMode()
{

    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Now when you hit start on the service you'll get a dialog asking if you want to attach. Its way easier then trying to attach manually.

Comment: I have managed to get the service to tick, but I cannot debug it.
When I attach it hits no break points even though its writing to the event log so I know its doing it, and if I add the debug.break it causes the service to crash!

Comment: Never mind, It was referencing the .net 4 client profile rather than the full version, this appears to be why I couldn't debug.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to files **Service.cs** and **Program.cs** and **Event Log** below...

I noticed that **System.Timers.Timer** does not work well in a Windows Service when the project's property *Output Type* is set to `Windows Application`.  However, it DOES work when project's property *Output Type* is set to `Console Application`.

The QUICKEST and SIMPLEST solution is to set the project's property *Output Type* to `Console Application`.  Console statements are ignored when the project's property *Output Type* is set to `Windows Application`.  No code change...  Just project settings change.

In a subsequent response, I shall submit an alternate solution wherein **System.Timers.Timer** will behave as expected in a Windows Service.  It involves adding "undocumented" code.

To understand what was going on, I added three breakpoints (Breakpoint 1, Breakpoint 2 and Breakpoint 3).  Breakpoints 1 and 2 are in **Service.cs** below and Breakpoint 3 is in **Program.cs** below (See comment: "// Breakpoint..." in code).  I ran the Windows Service with the project's property *Output Type* is set to `Windows Application` and logged all the results (See **Event Log** below).

What we see is the following (See *internal void TestStartupAndStop(string[] args)* method in **Service.cs** below):  The `OnStart` event triggers the *OnStart* method, wherein the timer is initialized successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception).  The `OnStop` event triggers the *OnStop* method, wherein objects are properly disposed successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception).  But then, something COMPLETELY UNEXPECTED occurs...  The `OnTimer` event triggers the *OnTimer* method, wherein the task is performed successfully TWICE (i.e., without throwing an exception) ***AFTER THE SERVICE HAS STOPPED!***

(*mind blown!*)

**File: Service.cs**

```
using System.Timers;

namespace <namespace>
{
    public partial class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        protected void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var methodName = "protected void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)";
            try
            {
                EventLogWriteEntry("Running Service...");
                EventLogWriteEntry("Do Task...");
                // :
                // :
                // :
                EventLogWriteEntry("Task Done...");
                EventLogWriteEntry("Service ran successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errorMessage = "Error running Service...";

                HandleGeneralException(errorMessage, ex, methodName);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            var methodName = "protected override void OnStart(string[] args)";
            try
            {
                EventLogWriteEntry("Starting Service...");

                System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                timer.Interval = double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Timer.Interval"]); // Set Interval to 5 seconds
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
                //timer.Enabled = true; // timer.Start() does the same exact thing
                timer.Start();

                EventLogWriteEntry("Service started successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errorMessage = "Error starting Service...";

                HandleGeneralException(errorMessage, ex, methodName);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            var methodName = "protected override void OnStop()";

            try
            {
                EventLogWriteEntry("Stopping Service...");
                EventLogWriteEntry("Do Clean-Up...");
                // :
                // :
                // :
                EventLogWriteEntry("Clean-Up Done...");
                EventLogWriteEntry("Service stopped successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errorMessage = "Error stopping Service...";

                HandleGeneralException(errorMessage, ex, methodName);
            }
        }

        // Note: Set project's property Output Type to Console Application.  Revert to Windows Application when done.
        // See comment in static void Main() in Program.cs
        internal void TestStartupAndStop(string[] args) // FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY!
        {
            this.OnStart(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop..."); // Console statements are ignored when Output Type is set to Windows Application.
            Console.ReadLine();
            this.OnStop(); // Breakpoint 1: Wait 60 seconds...
        }  // Breakpoint 2: Wait 60 seconds...
    }
}
```

**File: Program.cs**

```
namespace <namespace>
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            // Note: The If block is for testing interactively.
            // The Else block is the normal execution block of code.
            // No need to comment/uncomment code.
            // See comment in internal void TestStartupAndStop(string[] args) in Service.cs
            if (Environment.UserInteractive) // FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY!
            {
                var service = new Service();
                service.TestStartupAndStop(null);
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                { 
                    new Service() 
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
        } // Breakpoint 3: Wait 60 seconds...  Timer events fired AFTER here!
    }
}
```

**Event Log**

| Level | Date and Time | Source | Event ID | Task Category | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Breakpoint 1: Wait 60 seconds...* |  |  |  |  |  |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:24 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Starting Service... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:24 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Initialize timer... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:24 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Service started successfully. |
| *Breakpoint 2: Wait 60 seconds...* |  |  |  |  |  |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:25 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Stopping Service... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:25 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Do Clean-Up... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:25 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Clean-Up Done... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:25 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Service stopped successfully. |
| *Breakpoint 3: Wait 60 seconds... **Timer events fired AFTER here!*** |  |  |  |  |  |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Running Service... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Do Task... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Task Done... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Service ran successfully. |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Running Service... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Do Task... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Task Done... |
| Information | 5/31/2021 7:27 | ServiceEventSource | 0 | None | Service ran successfully. |