# System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed event not firing

Tags: c#, timer

I had created new `Timer` variable on my Window Form Application:

```
intervalTime = new System.Timers.Timer();
intervalTime.Interval = 5000;

intervalTime.Enabled = true;
Console.WriteLine(intervalTime.Enabled.ToString());
intervalTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(intervalTime_Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine(intervalTime.Enabled.ToString());
```

and my `Timer` would execute every 5 seconds with `ElapsedEvent`:

```
void intervalTime_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
      //Do something....
}
```

but `ElapsedEvent` not firing at all. How should I do to make it fired? I check that `intervalTime.Enabled` is `true`.

I had found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628039/system-timers-timer-timer1-elapsed-not-firing-help) before but it not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and not `System.Timers.Timer` here. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` has a `Tick` event that automatically fires every N milliseconds (that you can set using `Interval` property just like `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`). This is unlike `System.Timers.Timer` which fires `Elapsed` event only once and acts more like a time-bomb than a "scheduled ticker".

If you must use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, you should set `AutoReset` property to `True` for the event to occur repeatedly.

### EDIT

It seems like at some point they have changed the `AutoReset` property's default value to `true`; meaning that `System.Timers.Timer` now fires `Elapsed` event repeatedly by default, just like `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. However, note that [Microsoft explicitly recommends using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in WinForms applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), just like I did above.

Comment: Why System.Windows.Forms.Timer ? He's using a Console Application and there's no need synchronize timer with UI events.

Comment: @JuanK: I am using Window Form Application ^^

Comment: He has explicitly mentioned in the question body that he's using Windows Forms. Care to take back your downvote?

Comment: True Story. I still not seeing any need to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer to resolve your problem.

Comment: @dotNET System.Timers.Timer doesn't fire Elapsed event only once... actually  System.Timers.Timer fires the event each time elapsed Interval happens

Comment: @JuanK: [That's not correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You must use `AutoReset` or call `Start()` in `Elapsed` event for that to happen.

Comment: @JuanK: Time to take back your downvote again?! :)

Comment: @dotNET Take  a look at the code and verify it by yourself. Its working as I say with System.Timers.Timer  http://codepaste.net/qgfjsm

Comment: @JuanK: You are partly correct. They have actually set the default value of `AutoReset` property to `true`; that's why it fires repeatedly by default. IIRC, this used to be `false` in some earlier version of .NET. Even the documentation wording appears to mean that: **Generates an event after a set interval, with an option to generate recurring events**; implying that recurring events is an **optional** behavior, not the default one. So my answer too isn't technically incorrect. I'll rephrase it to make it more helpful though. A downvote is still harsh for this situation I'd say.

Comment: @dotNET I have tested the code with framework 2.0 => same behavior the event raises many times as expected without AutoReset or call Start(). /Maybe/ you're confusing with System.Threading.Timer. Additionally there's no recommendation about to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer unless you need to modify UI properties from ElapsedEvent. Nevertheless this isn't making a big difference in the question escenario. Both Timers could for sure supply the business needings for the question.

Comment: @JuanK: There IS a recommendation in favor of WinForms Timer if you read the MSDN article I linked in the EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: @JuanK: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is more favor of WinForms Timer because it could update Main UI Thread directly, in my case ^^

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the event handler before to start the timer. That is before you call `intervalTime.Enabled = true;`

```cs
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var intervalTime = new System.Timers.Timer();

            //Do IT HERE
            intervalTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(intervalTime_Elapsed);

            intervalTime.Interval = 5000;

            intervalTime.Enabled = true;
            Console.WriteLine(intervalTime.Enabled.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(intervalTime.Enabled.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static void intervalTime_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something....
            Console.WriteLine("New event fired");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had used your solution, but problem still occur, bro

Comment: I have tested that code, could you run my whole sample and verify? maybe you're not showing all the code you have.

Comment: I have updated to show full sample so you can try it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if we have to start this timer after we defined it.

Maybe we should do it like this:

intervalTime.Start();